# Getting ExamQuestion@143c8b3 as print out in console

Tags: java, class, methods, println, main-method

I have a have a class that has a method which takes a string. Then I have a method which returns the value of the above method. When ever I get the return value in my main class and print it the printed value is "ExamQuestion@143c8b3". How do I get it to print correctly?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you provided an example of your code that isn't working, by which I mean strip your code of everything that isn't required to show your problem and then place it in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you get the format "@" this is the default format of an object's toString() method.

Calling `System.out.println(question);` calls `ExamQuestion.toString()`. If the method isn't overridden, the version in the super class will be called, in this case it will be `Object`'s version.

So that's why you get ExamQuestion@143c8b3.

To fix this, put the following method in your ExamQuestion class:

```
public String toString() {
    // return a string that means something here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have ExamQuestion overriding toString().

Answer (score 1):

The output you are seeing is how java represents objects as strings.

The default behavior is:

```
this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(this.hashCode());
```

If you want the string representation of your object to be more clear, you should override the `toString()` method in your class.

Answer (score 1):

That is the default behaviour as explained by @ValekHalfHeart in his answer.

If you want to print your objects stuff then you need to override `toString` method in your class.

Say I have this code:

```
class MyClass{
   int a,b;
}
```

So when I make an object of this class and pass it to `println`:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  MyClass m = new MyClass();
  m.a = 20;
  m.b = 30;
  System.out.println(m);
}
```

It will print something like `MyClass@143c8b3` as is your case.

So now if I want that whenever I pass my object to `println` it should print something else like values of my variables `a` and `b` should be printed.

Then I should override `tostring` method in `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass{
   int a,b;

   public String toString(){
     return "MyClass values: a = "+a+" and b = "+b;
   }
}
```

So now when I say this

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  MyClass m = new MyClass();
  m.a = 20;
  m.b = 30;
  System.out.println(m);
}
```

Its going to print `MyClass values: a = 20 and b = 30`

So you have to do that for your `ExamQuestion` class

Answer (score 0):

All classes inherit (implicitly) from `Object`, which has the `toString()` method, the implementation of which is producing the output you're seeing.

To have a meaningful String representation, you must *override* this method to provide an implementation that's suitable for your class.